# c# парсинг времени

Tags: c#, парсер

Добрый день! У меня есть строка такого вида

```
9д20ч 18 мин
```

Как можно спарсить эту строку, чтоб привести в нормальный вид?
В некоторых случаях, в дате не будет дней. То есть, мне как то надо узнать эти числа и переменным все расставить. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
(\d+\s*д)?.*?(\d+\s*ч)?.*?(\d+\s*м)?
```